# Display one drop down at time and close the others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two dropdown menus which are displayed when the user clicks them. They are hidden by default. Is there a way to close the dropdown which is not being clicked?. For example the 'client' menu should be closed once I click the 'car' menu.

```js
/* display the dropdown when client, vehcile or module are clicked */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content */
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block")
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    else
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: LinetoCircular;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}


/* hidden by default, make the content shifts under the title */

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #575757;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.dropdown-container a:hover {
  background-color: #414141;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">
        <div>Client</div>
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
    <a href=''>first element</a><br>
    <a href=''>second element</a><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="dropdown-btn">
            <div>Car</div>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
      <a href=''>first element</a><br>
      <a href=''>second element</a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there is a possible way to not change a lot in the code, that would be appreciated.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2c9pbyvo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require, loop through all the `.dropdown-btn` elements and hide the ones which are not relevant to the clicked button:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')).forEach(el => {
  if (el !== dropdownContent)
    el.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')).forEach(el => {
      if (el !== dropdownContent)
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });

    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block")
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    else
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: LinetoCircular;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* hidden by default, make the content shifts under the title */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #575757;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.dropdown-container a:hover {
  background-color: #414141;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">
    <div>Client</div>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
    <a href=''>first element</a><br>
    <a href=''>second element</a><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="dropdown-btn">
      <div>Car</div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
      <a href=''>first element</a><br>
      <a href=''>second element</a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works so fine thanks. I got one last question, i have two arrows for each dropdown. like this `<div >svg_arrow_here</div>` just under the div of the client and the car. How can i rotate back the arrow of the non displayed dropdown?. For now i rotate them when they are being displayed

Comment: You can amend the content of the div when the parent is clicked. It's hard to say exactly what you need to do without seeing an example, though. I'd suggest starting a new question for it

Comment: The best would probably be to introduce a new class `.expanded` and toggle this class in your JS - That way you can extend the behavior on your dropdown menus and children without changing the js - even if they were introduced later to your html.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did, here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241177/rotate-back-caret-after-closing-dropdown-menu

Comment: @Lapskaus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241177/rotate-back-caret-after-closing-dropdown-menu can you try to edit my new question? i couldnt access the carets.