# Dropdown menu toggle rotate arrow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two dropdown menus which are hidden. They are displayed once the user clicks one of them. when one dropdown menu is open, it closes the other one. This work so far so good. I added an SVG caret to each menu and its getting down rotated (90 deg) when the user clicks a menu.

How can I rotate it back to its initial place(-360deg) when another menu is open.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')).forEach(el => {
      if (el !== dropdownContent)
        el.style.display = 'none';
        /* if its possible rotate it back here, i couldnt access the carets here */
    });

    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block")
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    else
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```
.dropdown-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: LinetoCircular;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* hidden by default, make the content shifts under the title */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #575757;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.dropdown-container a:hover {
  background-color: #414141;
}
```

```
<div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">
      <div id="wrapper">
          <div>Client</div>
          <div id="rotate1" class="transformButton" style="position: relative; left: 104px; top: 2px;"><!--this is the caret, may not be visible because its local--></div>
      </div>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
    <a href=''>first element</a><br>
    <a href=''>second element</a><br>
  </div>
  <div>
      <button class="dropdown-btn">
          <div id="wrapper">
              <div>Car</div>
              <div id="rotate2" class="transformButton" style="position: relative; left: 104px; top: 2px;"><!--this is the caret, may not be visible because its local--> </div>
          </div>
      </button>
  </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="client_properties/" style="height: 30px;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">+</span>Add new</a><br>
      <a href=''>first element</a><br>
      <a href=''>second element</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Caret is invisible here, but i wrote the  for it. It should just be next to each dropdown.
Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2mwr4y68/

Comment: Your HTML is not formatted well. Take a closer look at your outer `<div>` wrappers. They are misplaced. Also, there's not a single line of jQuery in there...

Comment: `<div id="wrapper">` twice? You sould know what ID is used for! You cannot have duplicate IDs

Comment: `<button>` should only contain contextual elements like `<span>` `<i>` etc, not block-level elements like `<div>` `<p>` etc...

Comment: Stop using inline `style=""` just like you hopefully don't use inline `on*=""` handlers. Styles should be inside your Stylesheet.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah the formatting got broken as i copied that, i will edit the code thanks for the infos. Do you have an idea about the rotation that i asked for?

Comment: Instead of `<br>` use a List `<ul>` with `<li>` if that's a markup you need. I'm just starting with basics before providing a solution...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, im working on that and trying to keep it clean and valid.

Comment: I cleaned the HTML in my answer, improved it and gave you a hint how to use the `:before` pseudo for the different arrows....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the [Details HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details):

```css
.dropdown-container { 
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #575757;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Client</summary>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Some content one
  </div>
</details>

<details class="dropdown">
  <summary>Car</summary>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Some content two
  </div>
</details>
```

Otherwise by using JavaScript:

- add a class to the wrappers i.e: `class="dropdown"`
- Create a CSS class `.is-open` that will be added to the wrappers
- Toggle that class using JS

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

dropdowns.forEach(el => {

  const button = el.querySelector(".dropdown-btn");
  
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Close all
    [...dropdowns].filter(x => x != el).forEach(el => el.classList.remove("is-open"));
    // Toggle one
    el.classList.toggle("is-open");
  });
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; font:14px/1.4 sans-serif; }

.dropdown-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-btn::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\25BC";
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #575757;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown.is-open .dropdown-btn:before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown.is-open .dropdown-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button">Client</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Some content one
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button">Car</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Some content two
  </div>
</div>
```

The above is not intended to work with multiple collection-groups of `.dropdown`
If that's the case, wrap the above to account for groups of `.dropdown`s

Comment: you are a hero! thanks. the caret content in the before selector was a hack!! thanks!