# how to create openable accordion

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I got problem with my accordion script. I'm trying to create accordion looking like this in screen [image]

```js
var accordionItem = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item');
var accordionContent = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item_content');
var accordionButton = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-btn');

for (i = 0; i < accordionButton.length; i++) {
  accordionButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    accordionContent[i].classList.add('opnen')
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-item_header">
    <h3>Experience</h3>
    <button class="accordion-btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item_content container">

  </div>
</div>
```

After click on my button i got console error [image]

I want to open my content box after clicking only button in accordion header div. How to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited my question. I've got Uncaught TypeError in browser console

Comment: Your error message suggests that `accordionContent[i]` does not exist. If you want to query element that is related to the clicked button, use DOM traversal methods instead, eg access the parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

***Issue***:
Your `i` variable is **globallly scoped**, therefore at the time you click it — its value already incremented to `1` - and there's no such `accordionContent[1]` element.

***Solution***:
**Scope** your variable using the `let` keyword: `let i = 0;`

```js
var accordionItem = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item');
var accordionContent = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item_content');
var accordionButton = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < accordionButton.length; i++) {
  accordionButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    accordionContent[i].classList.add('open');
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-item_content { display: none; }
.accordion-item_content.open { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-item_header">
    <h3>Experience</h3>
    <button class="accordion-btn" type="button" aria-label="Toggle content">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item_content container">content here</div>
</div>
```

Anyways, I might suggest you another way to implement the desired, and that's by using `data-*` attribute selectors like in this related answer: [Toggle elements on buttons click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73010188/383904) or [Dropdown Menu Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64241177/383904)

Or by using the [Details element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

```html
<details>
    <summary>Experience</summary>
    content here
</details>
```